# Blacklist list of IPs from File Centos 7.5

Tags: linux, firewall, centos-7, firewalld

I've to deny access from set of IP set from specific country and downloaded the list from http://www.ipdeny.com/ site.
I tried to block this set using

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --ipset=blacklist --add-entries-from-file=/home/cn.zone
```

but that got failed. Error

> Error: INVALID_IPSET: blacklist.

How can i block them.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't create a ipset before your command. first use this command and create a ipset
then use your command.

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --new-ipset=blacklist --type=hash:net --option=family=inet --option=hashsize=4096 --option=maxelem=200000
```